# C++ clock() function giving incorrect values

Tags: c++, clock

I was trying to program a Timer class (unaware that boost had one), then when that wasn't working, I tried to just output the value of clock(), using this code:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
 for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
 {
  std::cout << std::clock() << " ";
 }
 return 0;
}
```

When I run the program, I get a series of 0s. I have a similar experience when using boost thread sleep functions to spread out timing a little longer (although after a few seconds, it jumps from 0 to 10,000 and keeps outputting 10,000).

I'm running Gentoo Linux. Is this a platform thing? A C++ thing? What's going on?

Edit: Strangely the jump to 10000 comes after a number of **seconds**, not milliseconds. When I was sleeping my thread for a second at a time, it took five or six seconds to get to 10000. However, if I'm understanding correctly. The time the thread spends sleeping doesn't contribute towards the clock() count? (Which would make sense; why would it be executing clock cycles if it's sleeping?)

Comment: Exactly. When your thread sleeps, the system doesn't schedule it to the CPU and the `clock()` count is frozen. In your example, it is only the short time spans between waking up and sleeping again that count.

Comment: Note that clock() returns CPU time for the entire program, summing all threads. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5035854/13422

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `clock()` return value is specified in microseconds. But typical granularity of whatever low-level system call the `clock()` implementation uses is much lower. So it seems that on your system the granularity is 10ms. Also note that `clock()` does **NOT** measure real time - it measures CPU time used by the program. So the time flows when your program controls the CPU, and it freezes when your program is suspended - sleeping, for example.

Comment: Note -- it doesn't **have** to be microseconds. (Hence the reason for the CLOCKS_PER_SEC macro)

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/.  This says that it is not guaranteed to be any specific unit.  You have to use the CLOCKS_PER_SEC macro to find the time in real units.  As for 10ms resolution, I think that isn't terribly uncommon.

Comment: However, in a POSIX-conformant system it *does* have to be microseconds (`CLOCKS_PER_SEC` is mandated to be 1000000).

Comment: POSIX mandates CLOCKS_PER_SEC == 1000000. So unless you're on some old wacky OS, it's going to be microseconds :).

Comment: Some of us code for ISO, some for POSIX. I'm not sure that Linux is entirely POSIX-compliant anyway. Linus' attitude to standards compliance was, shall we say, "spotty", at least in the early days (no idea about now). Not that that's a bad thing, most times pragmatism beats dogmatism in the real world :-)

Comment: When the Linux manpage for clock(3) says that POSIX requires CLOCKS_PER_SEC to be 1000000, you can be sure that's because Linux (or more likely glibc) is implementing it that way.

Comment: I doubt that any libc maker (even Microsoft!) would pass on such low-hanging compatibility fruit like this. Making CLOCKS_PER_SEC equal 1000000 is a trivial way for one more POSIX compatibility-point.

Comment: @slacker - Or one more Posix incompatibility point.  Microsoft tries very hard to be incompatible when they think they can use the incompatibility to lock in users.

Comment: @Omnifarious:
Oh come on, do you think people coding exclusively for windows would even *use* unixish C APIs like `clock()`? There are a bunch of Win32 APIs that do the same task, while accomplishing the vendor lock-in objective much more effectively. `clock()` is needed to port existing *nix code to windows, not the other way around.

Comment: @slacker `clock()` isn't «unixish API», it's a part of C++ standard. However I'd add that I relatively earlier was needed to begin to code for Win, and I was astonished how it is hard to program with C++ there with comparison to GNU/Linux. I guess now I know why some peoples claims C# to be a good lang 

Answer (score 0):

`std::clock`'s resolution is unspecified. In most cases, it's resolution is going to be about `10ms`. Hence the jump.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < 500; ++j )
      {
         std::cout << j << " ";
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
      std::cout << std::clock() << std::endl;
   }
   std::cout << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

On my system, I see the return value of clock() staying at 0 until at some point it jumps to 10000. It stays at 10000 till the end. If I remove the std::cout in the inner loop, the return value of clock() stays at 0 all the way through. Looks like clock() returns values in increments of 10000 only.

If I change the inner loop to compute the square root of j and print the return value of sqrt(), the return value of clock() goes up to 50000, but is still increases in increments of 10000.

Answer (score 0):

on my 64 bit operating system the CLOCKS_PER_SEC speed is 1000.and the values of clock comes in milliseconds. perfect timing will be extracted from the code below.

```
int main(){

clock_t a,b;
int c,d,e,f;
c=clock();
scanf("%d",&e);
d=clock();
f=(d-c)/CLOCKS_PER_SECOND;
printf("timing is %d seconds",f);/*for 64 bit operating system         
CLOCKS_PER_SECOND is 1000*/




}
```