# Why are my runtime numbers wrong when trying to measure how long a function takes to return?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have 30 vectors of sorted ints, the vectors range in size from 2<sup>0</sup> to 2<sup>30</sup>. I am trying to measure how long a binary search will take to find a value in each, but the reported time *speeds up* as the vectors get larger. The time doesn't actually take longer, the reporting is wrong.

Here's my code:

```
int main() {
    const unsigned int maxPower = 30;  // 2^maxPower
    long long n = 1 << maxPower;  // n = 2^i

    for (int i = 0;  i <= maxPower; ++i) {

        std::vector<long long> haystack = getVector(i);  // returns a sorted vector of size i
        long long needle = haystack.size()/2 + 1;

        clock_t t1 = clock();  // start timer
        binary_search(haystack, needle);
        clock_t t2 = clock();  // end timer

        clock_t dt = t2 - t1;
        double clocks_per_rep = ((double)dt)/n;
        double seconds = clocks_per_rep/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        std::cout << seconds << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried using `high_resolution_clock` as well, but couldn't get that to even display anything but 0's.

---

EDIT: My original problem has been solved, but now I have a new one: there's hardly any variation in my timings, even when some take much longer than others. Here's my new code and output:

```
int main() {
    const unsigned int maxPower = 30;  // 2^maxPower
    long long n = 1 << maxPower;  // n = 2^i

    for (int i = 0;  i <= maxPower; ++i) {

        std::vector<long long> haystack = getVector(i);  // returns a sorted vector of size i
        long long needle = haystack.size()/2 + 1;

        clock_t t1 = clock();  // start timer
        ternary_search(haystack, needle);
        clock_t t2 = clock();  // end timer

        clock_t dt = t2 - t1;
        double seconds = (double)dt/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        std::cout << seconds << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
1e-06
1e-06
1e-06
0
1e-06
1e-06
0
0
1e-06
0
0
1e-06
0
0
0
0
1e-06
1e-06
1e-06
4e-06
3e-06
3e-06
1e-06
2e-06
3e-06
3e-06
3e-06
2e-06
3e-06
3e-06
3e-06
```

Comment: I think I found a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597404/c-clock-function-giving-incorrect-values.

Comment: Post `getVector`. (And make a new question out of your followup.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming no bias in search, `dt` is expected to be `O(log(N))`. When you compute

```
double clocks_per_rep = ((double)dt)/n;
```

`clock_per_rep` is `O(log(N)/N)`. It makes sense that the value goes down as `N` goes up.

It makes sense to me to omit the division by `n`.

```
clock_t dt = t2 - t1;
double seconds = (double(dt))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Comment: Ah that was leftover code I overlooked, thanks. However, I'm still having similar issues -  I updated the post with the updated code and description

Comment: You updated your question in a way that makes my answer useless :) :)

Comment: I apologize I'm not too familiar with the proper way to follow up on this site, I reverted the changed

Comment: I understand. Does the other post answer your question? If the answer is yes, then that's all that matters.

Comment: I'm not positive but I don't think so. The first 15 or so print statements print immediately, but then they slow down exponentially, taking more than 10 seconds each near the end. Two times will be identical even when one time will take twice as long as the previous.

Answer (score 0):

A binary search takes worst case O(log N). In your case that means 1 to 30 comparisons. Best case the first comparison is already right and returns directly.

You are trying to measure the time it takes to make 1-30 comparisons, so basically no time at all. I'm a bit surprised you get anything but 0 and 1e-06. Which seems to be the accuracy of your clock. Your cpu is probably clocked more than 1000 times faster.

You should do a loop to do many searches and then average that per search to get better accuracy. You are also only testing finding one specific value. Have you carefully constructed that choice to be a worst case? If not why not search for every value in the vector once?

My suggestion would be to use 3 loop:

```
N = 1
Outer loop: loop until the time difference between start and finish is >1s.
    N = 2 * N
    start clock
    Middle loop: repeat N times
        Inner loop: search for every value in the vector once
    end clock here
```

My best guess as to why the output takes exponentially longer each time is that `getVector(i)` takes that time. You have to initialize the whole vector and each pass it's twice as big. So this is kind of expected. But it can probably be optimized a lot. Likely you are growing the vector instead of initializing it with the right size.